# Solving two coupled ODEs without use of complex numbers

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a system of ODEs where $x, y$ are functions to be determined.

$$ x'(t) = 2x(t) y(t) $$
$$ y'(t) = y^2(t) - x^2(t) $$

It is pretty straightforward to solve this system by introducing complex function $z(t) = x(t) + i y(t)$, but I would like to solve this problem without use of complex analysis. I have tried ordinary technique of reducing this to single function but second order differential equation. I get the following for $x(t)$.

$$ 2x''(t) x(t) - 3 (x'(t))^2 + 4x^4(t) = 0 $$

But then, I am not sure on how to solve this.

I believe that the correct solution is the following.

$$ x(t) = \frac{x(0)}{(1-ty(0))^2 + (tx(0))^2} $$
$$ y(t) = \frac{y(0)-t((x(0))^2-(y(0))^2)}{(1-ty(0))^2 + (tx(0))^2} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}=2xy\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=y^2-x^2
\end{cases} $$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2-x^2}{2xy}$$
$$\frac{d(y^2)}{dx}=2y\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2-x^2}{x}=\frac{y^2}{x}-x$$
Let $u(x)=y^2$
$$\frac{du}{dx}-\frac{u}{x}=-x$$
This is a first order linear ODE which method of solving is well known.
$$u(x)=c_1\:x-x^2$$
$$\boxed{y(x)=\pm\sqrt{c_1\:x-x^2}}\tag 1$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\pm 2x\sqrt{c_1\:x-x^2}$$
$$dt=\pm\frac{dx}{2x\sqrt{c_1\:x-x^2}}$$
$$t=\pm\int \frac{dx}{2x\sqrt{c_1\:x-x^2}}=\pm \sqrt{\frac{c_1-x}{x}}+c_2$$
$$\boxed {x(t)=\frac{c_1}{1+(t-c_2)^2}} \tag 2$$
Then put Eq.$(2)$ into Eq.$(1)$ in order to find $y(t)$ .